# How to apply Sort function on a Map in scala?

Tags: java, html, scala, playframework

I am using MVC architecture in Play Framework in which the view part is a mix of scala and html. Now, I need to sort a Map coming from the controller layer in my view. As scala has no memory its being really hard to create a sort function to sort my map by timestamp.
Can anybody please help i'm really not able to solve this one as i am new to scala.

This is my First Question. Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: We need to know more to answer this, but probably something like `map.toList.sortBy(_.timestamp)` is what you want.

Comment: "scala has no memory" wait, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the timestamps are the *keys* of the map (i.e. it's a `Map[Long,B]`):

```
myMap.toSeq.sortBy(_._1) // yields a Seq[Tuple2[Long,B]]
```

That is, you're converting the map to a `Seq` first, so that element ordering will be preserved (maps are normally `HashMap`s, with an unpredictable ordering), then sorting that sequence by the first element of the key-value tuple.

If the timestamps are the values, replace the `_._1` with `_._2`.

Note that if you convert the intermediate `Seq` back to a `Map` (e.g. with `.toMap`), you'll be back in `HashMap` land again, and your sort will be gone.

So, this might be more like what you want:

```
scala.collection.immutable.SortedMap(myMap.toSeq: _*) // yields a SortedMap[Long, B]
```

Here, we convert `myMap` to a `Seq` just so that it can be passed to the varargs factory method of `SortedMap`.

Comment: There is also ListMap in the Scala collections, both mutable and immutable, which will keep the order of the keys.

Comment: Sure, but `ListMap` is there to preserve insertion order, but we want ordering.  Personally, I have no use for `ListMap`, its performance characteristics make it unsuitable for most uses I care about.